# How to generate CASE expression in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have relatively simple query which I don't know how to express in EF:

```
SELECT BrandName,
    CASE BrandName
      WHEN 'LG' THEN 1
      WHEN 'Samsung' THEN 2
      WHEN 'Sony' THEN 3
      ELSE 100
    END as BrandWeight
FROM Brands
```

basically I need to return list of brands with each brand's "weight" - and weight is defined in the run time (as well as list of brands with weights).

Please note that this is a very simplified example. In reality we have a complex eCommerce website with lots of legacy code - and recently client has asked to add an option to display certain products first - either based on brand, or on some other conditions. And we have lot of logic which I just do not want to touch - pagination, search, etc - so my idea is to add that "weight" to initial "Select" query and then order by "weight", and then do the rest of the logic.

Comment: Why not create a table which maps candidate `BrandName` values to their `BrandWeight`, and just join to it?

Comment: as I said, it's more complex than just static brand and weight. In particular, users generate these rules in run time... And property dealing with that new table updates etc could be even complex I'm afraid.

Comment: you could create an `Expression` at runtime using `Expression.Condition`, but it would be lots of hard work; if possible, it would be much easier to apply back at the app tier

Comment: Isn't it easier to create a SQL CLR or regular function?

Comment: I'd keep the current query and apply the weight with the result from DB in the business logic layer.

Comment: @AD.Net i can't do that because pagination is done on DB level.

Answer (score 0):

worst case scenario:

```
from s in something
select new 
           {s.BrandName, 
             BrandWeight = s.BrandName == "LG" 
                                             ? 1 : s.BrandName == "Samsung" 
                                             ? 2 : s.BrandName == "Sony" 
                                             ? 3 : 100}
```

Basically, you can chain `if else` and that should work, but it's "ugly"